# Textbox ->quando usuario adiciona valor -> esse valor vai ser calculado com uma class calculo foi criada e retorna valor na proxima tela

Tags: c#

Olá estou com seguinte problema talvez alguém possa ajudar

eu estou preciso fazer na seguinte logica

eu criei a seguinte class

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

nessa class adicionei os métodos

agora que vem problema 
quando usuário digitar valor na textbox1 que no caso seria r1
fazer o valor da entrada do usuário entrar na variveis que esta na class calculo dentro do calculo fazendo o valor adicionado pelo usuário = v1 quando usuário adiciona valor textbox2 O valor entrar dentro r2 e assim consecutivamente 
textbox1 = r1
textbox2 = r2
textbox3 = r3
textbox4 = v1
textbox5 = v2
tipo isso valor atribuído pelo usuário entrar dentro da class calculo dentro das variáveis 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

AGORA AKI ELE RETORNA VALOR CALCULADO

VAMOS COM PARTES ENTÃO TALVES NÃO DEU PARA ENTENDER MUITO BEM

NESSA IMAGEM QUE ESTA AKI O USUARIO ADICIONARA UM VALOR NA TEXTBOX 
EXP:10,20,30,40,QUALQUER VALOR NOS CAMPOS QUE ESTÃO V1,V2,R1,R2,R3

Comment: A primeira parte class é calculo do circuito que entrar na textbox

Comment: Você quer exibir isso no mesmo formulário ou em outro?

Comment: Cara, a sua pergunta não faz muito sentido... apresentar o código é melhor do que tentar ilustrar

Comment: "VAMOS COM PARTES ENTÃO TALVES NÃO DEU PARA ENTENDER MUITO BEM"... Que bom que você interpretou isso. Reformule a sua pergunta, ela está beeem confusa. Não conseguimos entender o problema nem o que está tentando fazer.